# Count characters in field dynamically

Tags: php, javascript, forms, count, character

I would like to count characters in a form textarea field dynamically, I know there is a similar question about this but I am wondering if it can count from a certain number towards 0, as example while writing a tweet on Twitter.

This code could be in javascript, PHP, it doesn't really matter to me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery - Count characters in textarea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5371089/jquery-count-characters-in-textarea)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should help you out. Here is a [tutorial](http://www.reconn.us/content/view/34/46/) regarding usage - a demo is found below:

**Usage:**

```
<input name="text" onKeyDown="CountLeft(this.form.text, this.form.left,50);"
                   onKeyUp="CountLeft(this.form.text,this.form.left,50);">
```

**Javascript:**

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">

 function CountLeft(field, count, max) 
 {
     if (field.value.length > max)
         field.value = field.value.substring(0, max);
     else
         count.value = max - field.value.length;
 }

</SCRIPT>
```

[Demo - Credit to www.reconn.us](http://www.reconn.us/demo/character_counter.html)

Hope this helps.

Comment: For some reason my onKeyPress="return entsub(event)" in that field does not work when I enter this code?

Comment: Are you referring to the onKeyUp event? It may also help to look at the source of the demo.

Comment: Also - make sure that you created a field to hold the counter value. In the demo I believe that it is called "left".

Comment: no i am referring to the onkeypress event, as i want to sumbit the form when one presses the enter key.

Comment: I got the counter to display, it was a problem with the css, but the onkeypress event still does not work.

Comment: Oh and btw, how could I display the counter as simple text and not a field?

Comment: Using this sample styling - on the input that contains the count - add 'style = border: 0;' in the input tag.

Comment: Aha, yes of course. But could you help me with my onkeypress issue?

Comment: Working on it right now - not really sure why it isn't firing.

Comment: I think it has to do with that both onkeyup and onkeydown are specified - causing onkeypress to be rendered useless? I am not sure, I am not very good at javascript, but that's just my point of view. Isn't there a way to put this functionality inside the onkeyup/onkeydown event?

Answer (score 2):

With Javascript, use the KeyUp event handler, and check for the legnth-property on your text field on every event.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/nslr/C2CNS/