# Events after keypresses (jquery)

Tags: jquery, events, keypress

I have a textarea. After the user types X number of characters in the textarea I want a few different events to fire.

- append the first X characters typed into another textfield.
- expand the textarea to give more room to continue typing

I know I can use keypress events in jquery, but how can I set off a event after say 25 characters have been typed?

I'm current trying this:

```
$('#post-content-field').keyup(function () {
$('#post-title-field').val($("#post-content-field").val()).trigger('change');
                            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the `.length` of the value of the textarea after each keypress. If it is greater than or equal to 25, grab the first few characters and increase the textarea height.

```
$("textarea.affectMe").on("keyup", function(){
  if ( this.value.length >= 25 && !$(this).hasClass("done") ) {
    $(this).addClass("done");
    $(".threeChars").val( this.value.substring(0,25) );
  }
});
```

Note, I'm adding a class to the textarea so we don't do this over and over after each keypress when the length is greater than 25.

Demo: http://jsbin.com/afonar/edit#javascript,html

Comment: Thats exactly what I want to do. Knowing how to write it all is my hangup.

Comment: Thanks very much! That's doing exactly what I wanted. Much appreciated!

Comment: @user179846 I'm happy this answer worked for you. Please consider accepting it if it solved your problem. I noticed the answer you currently have selected still left you with questions.

Comment: Oh right. Didn't realize I could only select one correct answer. You both helped me out a bit, but yours was the best solution for my exact problem. Thanks again! Looking forward to showing off my ideas

Comment: This is really nice, I needed this for an older version of jQuery before 1.7 (`.on`) so I changed it to `.bind` and it works great.

Answer (score 1):

Use jquery and the countChar function below

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js"></script>
    <script>
        function countChar(val){
                                var len = val.value.length;
                                if (len >= 500) {
                                    val.value = val.value.substring(0, 500);
                                }else {
                                    $('#charNum').text(500 - len);
                                }
        };
    </script>
```

In HTML call the function like

```
<textarea id="field" onkeyup="countChar(this)"></textarea>
<div id="charNum">
</div>
```

The div will display the character count. You can do anything inside the function

Reference : [Count characters in textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5371089/jquery-count-characters-in-textarea)

Comment: Okay that works. It allows me to fire events after X characters. **But**: I cannot type more than X characters, and it continually replaces the text in the other field. How can I have it replace just once.

Answer (score 1):

That was for your reference you can do anything you like.
Remove the lines that stops you from adding more text

refer below

```
function countChar(val){
    var len = val.value.length;
     $('#charNum').text(len);
     if (len >= 500) {
                     // Copy
      }else {
            //DO anything
      }
};
```

Comment: Ah that works now. I see now how to test for length then use an if/else statement to fire events. How can I got about copying the first 25 characters to this other field ONCE?

Comment: inside the function write : 

str = val.value.substring(0, 25);

Then copy it to any element you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('textarea').bind('keyup', function(e){
    if(e.target.value.length === 25) {
        // do stuff
    }
});
```