# jQuery character count

Tags: jquery

I am working on a character count [based on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5371089/jquery-count-characters-in-textarea).
I would like to call the function on window load but seem to be having issues, otherwise everything works.
Can anyone lend a hand on getting the count on load please.
[heres my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nalagg/PrtXH/)

```
function countChar(val){
    var len = val.value.length;

    if (len >= 500) {
            val.value = val.value.substring(0, 500);
            $('#stat span').text(0);
    }else {
            $('#stat span').text(500 - len);
    }
}

$(function(){
    var inputT = $('#descTextArea').val();
    //countChar(inputT);//this is breaking the code

    $('#descTextArea').keyup(function(){
        countChar(this);
    });

});
```

Comment: Why do you need the line that you know breaks the code? Seems to work just fine without it.

Comment: @j08691 i am trying to get the count as soon as the page loads, in other words if the `textarea` had preloaded text then would like to output the count

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this instead

```
function countChar(val) {
    var len = val.value.length;
    if (len >= 500) {
        val.value = val.value.substring(0, 500);
        $('#stat span').text(0);
    } else {
        $('#stat span').text(500 - len);
    }
}
countChar($('#descTextArea').get(0));
$('#descTextArea').keyup(function() {
    countChar(this);
});​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/PrtXH/1/)**

In your code you were passing a string (the value) into your function which is trying to get the length of an element. Instead, by calling `countChar($('#descTextArea').get(0));` you're just passing the element and allowing the function to find the length of the input as you intended.

Comment: 1 upvote after 16 seconds. I smell a throwaway voter account.

Comment: @AlienWebguy - I wish. I was kinda surprised myself.

Comment: I upvoted it. This is the correct answer as it passes the html element into `countChar` instead of a string. Guess I navigated to the question right after the answer was posted.

Comment: I wish I could read JavaScript as fast as you @Rfvgyhn. I'm impressed.

Comment: @j08691 thank you, can you explain this part a little please? `.get(0)`

Comment: @AlienWebguy This was just one of those cases where the bug jumped out at me. If only I could debug that easily all the time. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick and simple jQuery plugin I wrote.  All you need to do is `$("#element_id").jqCounter();` to give an input or textarea a character counter.  It responds to paste, changes and everything else I could think of.

**You must set the maxlength attribute for it to work**, ie. `<input maxlength=45 />` or `<textarea maxlength=45></textarea>`

```
<script>
(function($) {
    $.fn.extend({
        jqCounter : function(givenOptions) {
            return this.each(function() {
                var $this = $(this),
                    options = $.extend({
                        divider: "/"    // The diveder character between the count and max
                    }, givenOptions);
                // 0 chars or max count not set or already setup
                if($this.attr("maxlength") <= 0 || $this.hasClass("jqCounter")) return;

                // Add the counter text after the element
                var span= $("<span style=\"font-size:10px;\">"+$this.val().length+options.divider+$this.attr("maxlength")+"</span>")
                .insertAfter($this);

                // Add a class
                $this.addClass("jqCounter")
                // React to keypresses, changes, paste, etc. and change the counter
                .on('focus blur propertychange change input paste keydown keyup keypress', function(){
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        var maxChars = $this.attr("maxlength"),
                            txtLength = $this.val().length;
                        span.text( txtLength + options.divider + maxChars );
                        },
                    1);
                });
            });
        }
    });
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function()
{
  // All text areas will have a content counter
  $("textarea").jqCounter();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use $(document).ready() to bind your event handlers when the window loads, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#descTextArea').keyup(function(){
      countChar(this);
 });
});
```

Comment: this is for grabbing the text on keystroke, im talking about when the page reloads

Comment: it's irrelevant for jsfiddle, it automatically wraps your code with $(window).load

Comment: Thanks @Michal Klouda, I had no idea!