# jQuery Char Count Variable Issue

Tags: jquery

I was having a look at various methods of using a character count in jQuery and found one and modified it and implemented it but I am having a bit of an issue with it. Just wondering if you guys could give me any pointers as to where I may be going wrong.

This is what I have for the code:

```
function countChar(val) 
{
    var len = val.value.length;

    if (len >= 500)
    {
        val.value = val.value.substring(0, 500);
        $('.stat').text(0);
    }
    else 
    {
        $sv = (500 - len);        
        $('.stat').text($sv);
        if ($sv <= 20)
        {           
            $('.stat').css({'border': '1px solid #C33', 'color': '#C33', 'background-color': '#F6CBCA'});
        }
        else if ($sv >= 21 && $sv <= 150)
        {
            $('.stat').css({'border': '1px solid #9F6000', 'color': '#9F6000', 'background-color': '#FEEFB3'});
        }
        else
        {
            $('.stat').css({'border': '1px solid #090', 'color': '#090', 'background-color': '#DFF2BF'});
        }

    }
}

countChar($('#notes').get(0));
$('#notes').keyup(function() {
    countChar(this);
});
```

My ('#notes') is just a normal textarea.

I have a fiddle for it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wilcochris/PrtXH/42/):

It is based on the question found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12751056/jquery-character-count)

When I implement it on my page, it wasn't showing up. Upon looking at firebug, it is giving me the following error:

> TypeError: val is undefined

From my understanding, this error means you need to declare it using a var.

I have done this and then I get the following error:

> TypeError: val.value is undefined

I did try doing a var on val.value but that threw up a syntax error.

I did try using var val in the countChar() and it gives the following error:

> SyntaxError: missing formal parameter

I just can't seem to see what I am missing as it works in the fiddle just the way I would like it to.

Any pointers would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're passing an element, and for some reason you think it's a good idea to define a variable where the arguments to pass that element to the function should be ?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what the issue is because the jsfiddle example you provide seems to be working fine.

Comment: I can't replicate the issue on the fiddle. I don't know why FF and Chrome are throwing these errors.

Comment: Emile: That was my bad, i've fixed the code now

Comment: Change constructor to `function countChar(val) {}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue appears to be that I had put it outside of document.ready without even realising that I had. It works like a charm now