# Twitter textarea count characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

i want do the follow in js. Someone know how to do this?

```
http://s7.directupload.net/file/d/3361/587yctzg_jpg.htm
```

Here a start: http://jsfiddle.net/HgfPU/10/

```
    <textarea></textarea>

    <strong>You have <em id="count"></em> characters remaining</strong>

    <script>

    maxCharacters = 160;

    $('#count').text(maxCharacters);

$('textarea').bind('keyup keydown', function() {
    var count = $('#count');
    var characters = $(this).val().length;

    if (characters > maxCharacters) {
        count.addClass('over');
    } else {
        count.removeClass('over');
    }

    count.text(maxCharacters - characters);
});

</script>
```

Thank you!

**Update**

Found a solution here:

http://jsfiddle.net/X7d8H/23/

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5371089/count-characters-in-textarea)

Comment: What have you tried ? Stackoverflow isn't about asking people to make code for you. Try something, and if you're stuck, we'll be happy to help.

Comment: It seems like it is already counting.. what is not working?

Comment: The background-color of the overflow text should be red.

Answer (score 0):

Using a regular text-field, there's no way you can apply style to text.

You may want to use selection to mark text which is invalid, or use a Rich Text Editor, but it's using something huge for a very small need.

Comment: You should consider answer your own question then, as it might interest other members.

Comment: do u like to count the text on the selection