# Textarea count characters validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

i'm writing an asp page using vb.net and i need to count the number of characters in my textarea and display the message:"X characters Remaining."

that's my asp code:

```
  <td valign='top'>
                <textarea rows="5" id="content_txt" name="TextArea1" runat="server" maxlength="50"></textarea>
            </td>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Count characters in textarea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5371089/count-characters-in-textarea)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mc39q/)

HTML:

```
<textarea rows="5" id="content_txt" name="TextArea1" runat="server" maxlength="50"></textarea>
<p id="message"></p>
```

JS:

```
var area = document.getElementById("content_txt");
var message = document.getElementById("message");
var maxLength = 50;
var checkLength = function() {
    if(area.value.length < maxLength) {
        message.innerHTML = (maxLength-area.value.length) + " characters remaining";
    }
}
setInterval(checkLength, 300);
```

Comment: Wonder why did you prefer time interval over events

Comment: Replace `<` with `<=` - fixes a problem where the count is stuck at 1.

Answer (score 3):

I have a little but functional solution my friend, try this:

HTML CODE

```
    <textarea name="message"placeholder="Reply message..." maxlength="155" onkeyup="counter(this);"></textarea>
<div id="counter_div">0/155</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT CODE

```
<script>
    function counter(msg){
        document.getElementById('counter_div').innerHTML = msg.value.length+'/155';
    }
</script>
```

This case limit 155 characters.

Comment: Upvote for a summarized solutions. Simple

Answer (score 1):

this will return current length of the textarea using jquery `var length = $('#content_txt').val().length;` and rest of the logic you have to give it a try..

Answer (score 0):

```
<td valign='top'>
  <textarea rows="5" id="content_txt" name="TextArea1" runat="server" maxlength="50"></textarea>
  <span id="character-count">100</span> characters remaining.
</td>


var totallength = 100;

$('textarea#input').on('keydown, keyup', function(e) {
     $('span#character-count').text((totallength - input.val().length));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  function fix(dis)
    {
      var total=50; // ho many you want to show
      var val = dis.value;

      var count = val.length;
      document.getElementById('remaining').innerHTML= total-count;
    }

    <td valign='top'>
        <textarea rows="5" id="content_txt" name="TextArea1" runat="server" maxlength="50" onkeyup="fix(this)"></textarea>
    </td>

    <p><span id="remaining">0</span> Characters remaining</p>
```