# Count and limit characters in textarea with dynamic value

Tags: jquery

I have a textarea with select list to put content into my textarea.
I know how to count the dynamic value from the select list, but if I write some text after putting value on the textarea, the counter doesn't work.
Any idea ?

Html :

```
<div id="selectmodelediv">
    <select>
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="1111">test1</option>
        <option value="222">test2</option>
    </select>
    <br/>
    <textarea id="targetText" name="targetText" class="champ_tel_txtarea" rows="6" cols="50"></textarea>
    <div id="compteur" class="compteur"></div>
</div>
```

Jquery :

```
$('select').change(function () {
    $('#targetText').val($('#selectmodelediv select').val()) //
    $('#compteur').text('255 characters left');
    var max = 255;
    var len = $(this).val().length;
    if (len >= max) {
        $('#compteur').text(' you have reached the limit');
    } else {
        var ch = max - len;
        $('#compteur').text(ch + ' characters left');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps.

Reference [Count characters in textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5371089/count-characters-in-textarea?rq=1)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="selectmodelediv">
    <select>
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="1111">test1</option>
        <option value="222">test2</option>
    </select>
    <br/>
    <textarea id="targetText" name="targetText" class="champ_tel_txtarea" rows="6" cols="50" onkeyup="countChar(this)"></textarea>
    <div id="compteur" class="compteur"></div>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

var max = 255;

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('select').change(function () {
    $('#targetText').val($('#selectmodelediv select').val()) //
    $('#compteur').text('255 characters left');

    var len = $(this).val().length;
    if (len >= max) {
        $('#compteur').text(' you have reached the limit');
    } else {
        var ch = max - len;
        $('#compteur').text(ch + ' characters left');
    }
});
})
function countChar(val) {
    var len = val.value.length;
    if (len >= max) {
        $('#compteur').text(' you have reached the limit');
    } else {
        var ch = max - len;
        $('#compteur').text(ch + ' characters left');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are not binding to the change event of the `textarea`, only the `select`. See here for a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/h2ejR/.

### JavaScript

```
function UpdateCharactersLeft(element) {
    var max = 255;
    var len = $(element).val().length;

    if (len >= max) {
        $('#compteur').text(' you have reached the limit');
    } 
    else {
        var ch = max - len;
        $('#compteur').text(ch + ' characters left');
    }
}

$('select').change(function () {
    $('#targetText').val($('#selectmodelediv select').val());
    UpdateCharactersLeft(this);
});

$('#targetText').on('keyup', function() {
    UpdateCharactersLeft(this);
});
```

### HTML

```
<div id="selectmodelediv">
    <select>
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="1111">test1</option>
        <option value="222">test2</option>
    </select>
    <br/>
    <textarea id="targetText" name="targetText" class="champ_tel_txtarea" rows="6" cols="50"></textarea>
    <div id="compteur" class="compteur"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss one key event. Try this:

```
  $('select').change(function () {
      vv = $(this).val();
      $('#targetText').val(function(i, old){return old+vv}).trigger('keyup');
  })
  $('#targetText').keyup(function(){
      $('#compteur').text('255 characters left');
      var max = 255;
      var len = $(this).val().length;
    if (len >= max) {
       $('#compteur').text(' you have reached the limit');
    } else {
        var ch = max - len;
        $('#compteur').text(ch + ' characters left');
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use all the following events:

```
.change
.keydown
.keypress
.keyup
.blur
.focus
```

So put your function in a variable li ke so:

```
var counter = function() {
    $('#targetText').val($('#selectmodelediv select').val()) //
    $('#compteur').text('255 characters left');
    var max = 255;
    var len = $(this).val().length;
    if (len >= max) {
        $('#compteur').text(' you have reached the limit');
    } else {
        var ch = max - len;
        $('#compteur').text(ch + ' characters left');
    }
});

$('select').change(counter);
$('select').keydown(counter);
$('select').keypress(counter);
$('select').keyup(counter);
$('select').blur(counter);
$('select').focus(counter);
```