# How to make word length limit in php

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a forum and I have a problem. How can I make a word length limit?So you can't post a word with 32+ characters.

Comment: Suppose I wanted to post a thread about  [pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis) on your forum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a css property

```
word-break: break-all;
```

say your word was saved with the tags

In the css file you should do this

```
p {
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

Basically this means that a word can break even though two letters are consecutive
so this:

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

Would become this:
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by setting the max-length value in a form like this:

```
<form action="demo_form.asp">
    Username: <input type="text" name="usrname" maxlength="10"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

See [here](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/examples/formex.php/) for more info on form length and php.

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for ;/ I don't wanna limit the post, I want to limit the characters in a word. So you can't post a word like this (AAAAAAAAAAAFAFSFHASJHFASKJFSHGAGFSAFJSAGFJSAGFJSGAFSGAFJSAGFSJAGF) , because it has more than 32 characters.

Answer (score 0):

In plain HTML???

```
<textarea maxlength="32"></textarea>
```

you can use Javascript to count number of characters that are in the textarea.

here is something similar using jQuery [Count characters in textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5371089/count-characters-in-textarea)

Answer (score 0):

You can for example `explode()` the post into words and use `count()` on each of them to get their length, but what is the point?

Comment: Ok I'll try this and I need it because see what's happening if there's no word length limit : http://i.imgur.com/UBKUKdP.jpg