# Javascript Character Counter for SMS TextArea in html

Tags: javascript, html, count, character, textarea

I've designed sms sending page to send SMS. I'm showing a character count counting down from 160, using Javascript. The problem is that I don't know how to calculate number of SMS after every 160 characters.

my code in js function:

```
function CountCharIndividual(txtIndividualMessage) {
        var count = document.getElementById(txtIndividualMessage).value.length;
        if (count > 1 && count <= 160) {
            document.getElementById('charstatus2').innerHTML = 160 - document.getElementById(txtIndividualMessage).value.length;
        }
        if (document.getElementById(txtIndividualMessage).value.length > 160 - 1) {
            document.getElementById('charstatus2').innerHTML = "Maximum characters reached & now " + "showing new count: " + document.getElementById(txtIndividualMessage).value.length;
        }
        if (document.getElementById(txtIndividualMessage).value.length >= 160) {
            document.getElementById('smsCount').innerHTML = 1;
        }
    }
```

It's showing for the first 160 characters in the smsCount's innerHTML but not increasing then on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count characters in textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5371089/count-characters-in-textarea)

Answer (score 1):

Try Below code, if it helps

```
function CountCharIndividual(txtIndividualMessage) {

  var count = document.getElementById(txtIndividualMessage).value.length;
  var maxLength = 160;
  var smsCount = parseInt(count / maxLength);
  if (smsCount > 0) {
    document.getElementById('smsCount').innerHTML = smsCount;
  } else {
    if (count > (maxLength - 1)) {
      document.getElementById('charstatus2').innerHTML = "Maximum characters reached & now " + "showing new count: " + count;
    } else {
      document.getElementById('charstatus2').innerHTML = maxLength - count;
    }

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the last `if condition` is the reason. Try as follows

```
function CountCharIndividual(txtIndividualMessage) {
        var count = document.getElementById(txtIndividualMessage).value.length;
        if (count >= 1 && count <= 160) {
            document.getElementById('charstatus2').innerHTML = 160 - count;
        }
        else if (count > 160 - 1) {
            document.getElementById('charstatus2').innerHTML = "Maximum characters reached & now " + "showing new count: " + count;
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('smsCount').innerHTML = parseInt(count / 160);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I want 'smsCount' to increase by 1 after every 160 characters in the 'charstatus2'. for example if 'charstatus2' = 160 then 'smsCount'=1 and when charstatus2=320 then 'smsCount'=2 and so on

Comment: @PrateekJahagirdar Please try the modified answer

Comment: rather using `parseInt(document.getElementById(txtIndividualMessage).value.length / 160);` use `Math.ceil(document.getElementById(txtIndividualMessage).value.length / 160);` to get the count

Comment: thanks Mr. Anil kumar that worked out but only thing is that it is showing me in the decimal.

Comment: @PrateekJahagirdar use `parseInt` to avoid decimal. and please try to use the edited code of the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use this logic

```
var limit = 160;   // it will be fixed value
var charCount = 170  // it will be dynamic value

var result = Math.ceil(charCount/limit)
```

Now **result** will show the number of sms consumed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate the total of characters in the textbox and divide it by message length with is 160 characters in your case

```js
function CountCharIndividual(txtIndividualMessage) {
        var count = document.getElementById(txtIndividualMessage).value.length;
        if (count > 1 && count <= 160) {
            document.getElementById('charstatus2').innerHTML = 160 - count;
        }
        if (document.getElementById(txtIndividualMessage).value.length > 160 - 1) {
            document.getElementById('charstatus2').innerHTML = "Maximum characters reached & now " + "showing new count: " + count;
        }
        if (document.getElementById(txtIndividualMessage).value.length <= 160) {
            document.getElementById('smsCount').innerHTML = 1;
        }
        else {
          document.getElementById('smsCount').innerHTML = (count - (count % 160)) / 160;
        }
    }
```

Comment: @PrateekJahagirdar you need to modify the last condition to calculate the number of SMS with the follwing line document.getElementById('smsCount').innerHTML = (count - (count % 160)) / 160;