# Why is my word counter not returning anything?

Tags: javascript, html, word-count

I made a simple words counter to count the number of words in an HTML text box. It takes the data from the inputText field in the html doc, and counts how many actual words are in it. I can not get it to display the word count in the box. What am I doing wrong?

```js
function count_words(evt) {
    var input = document.getElementById('inputText').value;
    var words = 0;
    input = count_words().replace(/(< ([^>]+)<)/g, '').replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
    input = input.replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '');
    words = input.split(' ').length;

    words = document.getElementById('numberOfWords').innerHTML;
}

window.onload = function (evt) {
    if (document && document.getElementById) {
        document.getElementById('btnConvert').onclick = count_words;
    }
}
```

```html
<textarea id="inputText" cols="30" rows="6">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</textarea>
<br>
<input type="button" id="btnConvert" value="Word Count">
<input id="numberOfWords" type="text" value="" size="6">
```

Comment: I think you after something like -> `document.getElementById('numberOfWords').innerText = words`

Comment: Shouldn’t `count_words().replace` be `input.replace`? Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors. You’re getting “`InternalError`: too much recursion”.

Comment: HUH `input = count_words().` <--- why is the method calling itself? Should be a error since it is infinite....

Comment: @Keith still getting an error "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceededthat" for the count_words().replace. That might have been an issue too tho.

Comment: @Keith Inputs don’t use an `innerText`. You mean `value` instead.

Comment: Try making this `document.getElementById('numberOfWords').value = words`

Comment: @user4642212  Yes, spot on.  Didn't look at the HTML in detail, probably because the OP was using innerHTML I assumed he was using some sort of label.  Although INPUT do have innerText nothing gets rendered with it & value is what the OP wants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
words = document.getElementById('numberOfWords').innerHTML;
```

This part is wrong. This means you are assigning `innerHTML` attribute value into `words` value.

Now, you are inserting value to `input` tag so you need to assign `words` value to `value` attribute.

```
document.getElementById('numberOfWords').value = words;
```

```
input = count_words().replace(/(< ([^>]+)<)/g, '').replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
```

And this part is wrong. `count_words()` should be replaced with `input`.

```js
function count_words(evt) {
    var input = document.getElementById('inputText').value;
    var words = 0;
    input = input.replace(/(< ([^>]+)<)/g, '').replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
    input = input.replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '');
    words = input.split(' ').length;

    document.getElementById('numberOfWords').value = words;
}

window.onload = function (evt) {
    if (document && document.getElementById) {
        document.getElementById('btnConvert').onclick = count_words;
    }
}
```

```html
<textarea id="inputText" cols="30" rows="6">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</textarea>
<br>
<input type="button" id="btnConvert" value="Word Count">
<input id="numberOfWords" type="text" value="" size="6">
```

Comment: You can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5371089/count-characters-in-textarea

Answer (score 0):

Few edits to your function should solve it

```
  function count_words(evt) {
    var input = document.getElementById('inputText').value;
    var words = 0;
    input = input.replace(/(< ([^>]+)<)/g, '').replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
    words = input.split(' ').length;
    document.getElementById('numberOfWords').value = words; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got, just got to change `count_words().replace` to `input.replace` and `words = document.getElementById('numberOfWords').innerHTML` to
`document.getElementById('numberOfWords').innerText = words`

```
function count_words(evt) {
    var input = document.getElementById('inputText').value;
    var words = 0;
    input = input.replace(/(< ([^>]+)<)/g, '').replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
    input = input.replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '');
    words = input.split(' ').length;

    document.getElementById('numberOfWords').value = words;
}

window.onload = function (evt) {
    if (document && document.getElementById) {
        document.getElementById('btnConvert').onclick = count_words;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code seems right, but in your explanation you still mention the incorrect `innerText`.