# How to validate texarea by max value using Javascript

Tags: javascript, textarea

I need to validate text area as following code,

my code as follows, here I need set maximum length as 10 and, if user trying to enter more than 10 need to prevent and if it is backspace or delete need to allow for deleting purpose. and also need to show remaining character count in a paragraph. But this code not working well. Its not preventing text input after 10.

```
<textarea id="txtxasa" class="message-content" onkeyup="Validate(event,this)"></textarea>
<p id="MsgContentRemainingLimit" class="message-character-limit">10 characters remaining</p>

function Validate(e,vald) {
    var code;
    var txtLength = vald.value.length;
    var remainingContent = 10 - txtLength;
    $('#MsgContentRemainingLimit').text(remainingContent);
    console.log(vald.value.length)

    if (!e) var e = window.event;
    if (e.keyCode) code = e.keyCode;
    else if (e.which) code = e.which; 

    if (txtLength >=10 && (code != 8 || code != 46))
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count characters in textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5371089/count-characters-in-textarea)

Comment: @devlincarnate No i need pure js here, without JQeury

Comment: @devlincarnate Sir, I also need to prevent input typing more than 10. its not showing in that question. I need help to that also

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding **maxlength="10"** to the **textarea**. I've done it and it works for me.

Comment: add it before the 'onkeyup' event

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript you can try like this

```js
let element = document.getElementById('input-name');
let countElem = document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML;

element.addEventListener('input', function() {

  let inputvalue = this.value;
  let maxLength = 10;

  //disable the input if reached the limit
  if (inputvalue.length > maxLength) {
    console.log('maximum character limit reached');
    this.disabled = true;
  }

  //count the numbers
  let count = parseInt(countElem, 10);
  document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = count - inputvalue.length;

  if (inputvalue.length > count) {
    document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = 0;
  }

});
```

```html
<p>
  <input placeholder="First Name" id="input-name" name="input">
</p>

<p>remaining characters:</p><span id="counter" style="font-size:25px; font-weight:600;">10</span><br>
```

In Html5 you can also use the `<input maxlength='10'>` to limit characters only as a frontend validation. `onkeyup` in your code will not work if the user copy text and right click and paste them.

Comment: I need to enable only backspace and delete keys when user enter 10 characters.